# How do I typeset vertical and horizontal lines inside a matrix?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

*(From the notation used in course notes for Stanford CS229 available online.)* I'm trying to typeset the following matrices made up of row or column vectors:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444807/matrix-and-vertical-lines-in-columns

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use rules to create the vertical and horizontal bars and then just put them into your array directy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\vertbar}{\rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex}}
\newcommand*{\horzbar}{\rule[.5ex]{2.5ex}{0.5pt}}

\[
A = 
\left[
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    \vertbar & \vertbar &        & \vertbar \\
    a_{1}    & a_{2}    & \ldots & a_{n}    \\
    \vertbar & \vertbar &        & \vertbar 
  \end{array}
\right]
\]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1ex}
\[
A =
\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    \horzbar & a^{T}_{1} & \horzbar \\
    \horzbar & a^{T}_{2} & \horzbar \\
             & \vdots    &          \\
    \horzbar & a^{T}_{n} & \horzbar
  \end{array}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: result of code]

Comment: If I use the exact code from above the vertical lines are not set correctly. Has anything changed?

Comment: No, the code still does exactly this for me.

Comment: I also copied your exact code into a new document in TeXStudio, and the vertical spacing in the first matrix is wonky. See [this image](http://i.imgur.com/piDYHDg.png).

Comment: @TravisBemrose Hmm, it seems there was a typo in the original code. I've changed the `[1ex]` to `[-1ex]`.  But Herbert's `\vrule` works nicely too.

Comment: Yep, once I clean up the \\ newlines and remove some extra ampersands that showed up, it works great now.  I'd been using \vert.

Comment: (Fixed the formatting in the answer.)

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\[
A = 
\left[
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    \vrule & \vrule & & \vrule\\
    a_{1} & a_{2} & \ldots & a_{n} \\
    \vrule & \vrule & & \vrule 
  \end{array}
\right]
\]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1ex}
\[
A =
\left[
  \begin{tabular}{c>{$}c<{$}c}
    --- & a^{T}_{1} & ---\\
    --- & a^{T}_{2} & ---\\
    & \vdots & \\
    --- & a^{T}_{n} & ---
  \end{tabular}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I used `---` in math mode, I got three minuses. I had to use `\text{---}` to make it work. But it seems to be working for you... any ideas why?

Comment: no, in math it is always ---. I used a tabular which is by default in textmode ...

Answer (score 3):

I like the following easy solution for vertical lines.

```
V = \begin{pmatrix}
\mid & \mid & & \mid \\
{\bf v}_{1} & {\bf v}_{2} & \cdots & {\bf v}_{r}\\
\mid & \mid & & \mid \\
\end{pmatrix}
```

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Comment: I think the question in Werner's comment isn't relevant to the question at hand. Perhaps it belongs as its own question?

Comment: While it might not be relevant to this question *per se*, it's relevant in general, as `\bf` (and others) are deprecated in their usage.

Comment: Perhaps I should have used something like \vec{v} or \mathbf{v}. It's an easy modification.