# How to Typeset a Vector

Tags: vector

How to typeset vector like this in latex

[image]

I came across an article

[How do I typeset vertical and horizontal lines inside a matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12910/how-do-i-typeset-vertical-and-horizontal-lines-inside-a-matrix)

which mentions below code

```
\[
U = 
\left[
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    \vertbar & \vertbar & & \vertbar \\
    u^{(1)} & u^{(2)} & \ldots & u^{(n)} \\
    \vertbar & \vertbar & & \vertbar 
  \end{array}
\right]
\]
```

and generates equation like this

[image]

I have trouble putting right part in the equation, How can I do it.

Comment: Member for more than 2 years without a MWE? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @CarLaTeX On searching for "typesetting vector" all I could find a simple typesetting for vectors. This one is little different, couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: You could add a simple matrix with the u's, we'll add the rules. Helping is fun but re-typing all is boring!

Comment: Can you refer any article where it is mentioned

Comment: Of course, but why should _I_ do it? Please, help us to help you. As is, your question shows no effort by you, it's a _just-do-it-for-me_ one.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Please see the updated question

Comment: I do not understand where your problem is. If you add `\in \mathbb R^{n \times n}` after `\right]`, the result should be the desired one.

Comment: Much better: as you can see, you've already got an answer this way. Next time remember to add a _complete_ MWE, your code snippet isn't compilable (even if the complete one can be copied from the link).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would prefer to use `bmatrix` from `amsmath`. The R can be done using `\mathbb` from `amssymb` (or `amsfonts`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
  U = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \vert & \vert & & \vert\\
    u^{(1)} & u^{(2)} & \ldots & u^{(n)} \\
    \vert & \vert & & \vert    
  \end{bmatrix}
  \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]