# Multiplication of vector and matrix

Tags: matrices

I want to show multiplication between this matrix:

```
z^{[1]} = \[
\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    \horzbar & w^{T}_{1} & \horzbar \\
    \horzbar & w^{T}_{2} & \horzbar \\
    \horzbar & w^{T}_{3} & \horzbar \\
    \horzbar & w^{T}_{4} & \horzbar \\
  \end{array}
\right]
```

and this vector:

```
[\  
\begin{align}
    y &= \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{m}
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

\]
```

But how can I show the matrix-vector multiplication?

Comment: please make your mwe compilable what is `\horzbar`.

Comment: Zarko who does you copy me? :-) I tried with Papeeria and the code gives me many errors of the user's source. +1 for your comment.

Comment: @Sebastiano, i'm lost in code :-(. i guessing that op look for `z^{[1]}y = <matrix><vector>`, but i'm not sure. maybe he like to have between `\cdot` as symbol for multiplication.

Comment: Honestly, I did not understand anything about what the user wants to do.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: It is a simple product between a matrix and a column vector.

Comment: you still not explain,. what is `\horzbar` and where is defined. product of matrix in vector you should write as by hand: `<matrix><column vector>`. what is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following the probable definition from [How do I typeset vertical and horizontal lines inside a matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12910/how-do-i-typeset-vertical-and-horizontal-lines-inside-a-matrix)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\newcommand*{\vertbar}{\rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex}}
\newcommand*{\horzbar}{\rule[.5ex]{2.5ex}{0.5pt}}
\begin{document}
\[
z^{[1]} = 
\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    \horzbar & w^{T}_{1} & \horzbar \\
    \horzbar & w^{T}_{2} & \horzbar \\
    \horzbar & w^{T}_{3} & \horzbar \\
    \horzbar & w^{T}_{4} & \horzbar \\  
  \end{array}
\right]
\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{m}
         \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

With some magical definition of `\horzbar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\def\horzbar{\text{magic}}

\begin{align*}
Z^{[1]}y &= \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
  \horzbar & w^{T}_{1} & \horzbar \\
  \horzbar & w^{T}_{2} & \horzbar \\
  \horzbar & w^{T}_{3} & \horzbar \\
  \horzbar & w^{T}_{4} & \horzbar \\ 
\end{array}\right]
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_{1}  \\
  x_{2}  \\
  \vdots \\
  x_{m}
\end{bmatrix} \\
{} &= \begin{bmatrix}
  b_{1}  \\
  b_{2}  \\
  \vdots \\
  b_{m}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there also a magical definition? :). I upvote the magical command.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code substituting in place of the letters what you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{array, amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[  \mathbf{z^{[1]}}\cdot \mathbf{y}=
  \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc}
      \rule[.2ex]{1em}{0.2pt} & w^{T}_{1} &  \rule[.2ex]{1em}{0.2pt}\\
      \rule[.2ex]{1em}{0.2pt} & w^{T}_{2} &  \rule[.2ex]{1em}{0.2pt}\\
      \rule[.2ex]{1em}{0.2pt} & w^{T}_{3} & \rule[.2ex]{1em}{0.2pt}
    \end{array}
  \right]\cdot
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      x_1\\
      x_2\\
      \vdots\\
      x_n
    \end{array}
  \right]
\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, this is better than `magic`, however from math point of view, the dimension of the matrix and the vector does not match :-)

Comment: The best users, like you, are authorized to edit my answer. Authorized! :-)

Comment: i'm not a mathematician; in my profession, math was only the main tool :-), so i doubt that i'm competent for this :-). hopefully op know what (s)e need/doing :-).