# Matrix and vertical lines in columns

Tags: matrices

Can someone please tell me how I get vertical lines in the columns of a matrix like it is shown in the picture?

[image]

I started with `... = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda A' & \mu B' & \tau C' \end{pmatrix} ...`

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12910/how-do-i-typeset-vertical-and-horizontal-lines-inside-a-matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a \vline

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$ M = \begin{pmatrix}
\vline & \vline & \vline \\
\lambda A' & \mu B' & \tau C' \\
\vline & \vline & \vline
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Glad it helped! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please consider to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Is there a similar `hline` command for row vectors?

Answer (score 6):

Use `\mid` as ordinary table entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ M =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \mid & \mid & \mid \\
    \lambda A' & \mu B' & \tau C' \\
    \mid & \mid & \mid
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]