# How to use the | in multilines of a matrix in LaTeX?

Tags: lyx

I'm using LyX. I came across with the following Matrix:

[image]

I could use the following LaTeX for that:

```
\begin{bmatrix}| & |\\
\underline{x}_{1} & \underline{x}_{2}\\
| & |
\end{bmatrix}
```

But is it the right way? What If I want the `|` in multilines? Then I'll just use the `|` in each place. I'm sure there is a better way for that.

Comment: Do you just need to separate two columns like so? https://imgur.com/tYz9rTe

Comment: @antshar Thanks for the reply but not. That's easy. I would like to have `|` on the top and bottom and `x_1` in the middle.

Comment: Something like that? https://imgur.com/pfYyIC8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this question is a duplicate of this: [How do I typeset vertical and horizontal lines inside a matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12910/how-do-i-typeset-vertical-and-horizontal-lines-inside-a-matrix)

Here I put a small code where I have changed the parameters of vertical rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand*{\vertbar}{\rule[-1.5ex]{1.1pt}{3ex}}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{bmatrix}\vertbar &\vertbar\\
\underline{x}_{1} & \underline{x}_{2}\\
\vertbar & \vertbar
\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```