# special vector denote by Zero having extra line

Tags: fonts, mathtools, math-fonts

I want to show the vector of (0,0,...,0) by 0 that have extra line. How can I do it? I want to use this vector as special. so I use a lot of this notation.

I currently denote the vectors

```
$(0,0,\dots‎ ,‎0)\in ‎\mathbb{R}^{n}‎$
```

by `‎$‎‎\mathbb{O}$`. I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Something like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12910/how-do-i-typeset-vertical-and-horizontal-lines-inside-a-matrix

Comment: By "0 that have extra line", do you mean a double-struck or "blackboard bold" `0` character? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of matrixes like `bmatrix`, `pmatrix` https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Matrices

There are four types of dots:
– `ldots` horizontal dots on the line
– `cdots` horizontal dots above the line
– `vdots` vertical dots
– `ddots` diagonal dots

And you need `vdots` vertical dots.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\in {R}^{n}
$   

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that you apply whatever notational convention you've been following so far in your paper(s) to denote vectors to the zero-vector as well. E.g., if you write `\vec{v}` or `\mathbf{v}` -- to mention just two well-established vector-related notational conventions -- to denote that `u` and `v` are vectors, then just write either `\vec{0}` or `\mathbf{0}` to denote that `0` is a vector (an n-tuple, to be specific) and not a scalar.

Oh, and do be careful with writing a (row) vector as `(0,0,\dots‎ ,‎0)`: This notation is more commonly encountered for typesetting *sequences* of numbers, not vectors. Thus, do consider replacing `(0,0,\dots‎ ,‎0)` with `\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{pmatrix}`.

[image]

Observe the use of `'` to denote transposition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{pmatrix}' = \vec{0} = \mathbf{0}$
\end{document}
```